# ProgressBar not displayed

Tags: android, progress-bar

Because if I put a ProgressBar in a LinearLayout Invisible,is not displayed when the layout is made ​​visible at runtime?

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/new_login_box" android:visibility="invisible"
                android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dip" android:id="@+id/layout_label_upload"
                android:layout_weight="0" android:orientation="vertical">
                <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_upload"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#000000" 
                    android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>
                <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/listview_upload"
                    android:layout_margin="5dip" android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make it like android:visibility="visible" in LinearLayout and run it once and check whether its displaying or not. BTW whats your  parent layour?

Comment: The parent is the FrameLayout

Comment: With android:visibility="visible" in LinearLayout is displayed

Answer (score 0):

try removing `android:layout_weight="0"` from your linearlayout.